# Unable to map Firebase db items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

edit: including codepen:
https://codepen.io/hugerobots/pen/YeMWbY?editors=1010

Following is a pretty simple exercise in mapping database items to output into a `<ul>` per child database item.

The error after rendering (everything works until I implement the `map` below).

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

The example I'm following along with is a few years old, so there might be some changes to what I'm following, with caveats to updated instruction from the actual Firebase documentation.
https://css-tricks.com/firebase-react-part-2-user-authentication/

Where I'm getting turned around is probably the repetition of using `items` and `item` in reference to the actual items in the database and use of the term in the code below.

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('vendors');
    const item = {
        name: this.state.user.displayName || this.state.user.email,
        email: this.state.user.email,
        vendorName: this.state.user.vendorName,
        vendorType: this.state.user.vendorType
    }
    itemsRef.push(item);
    this.setState({
        username: '',
        email: '',
        vendorName: '',
        vendorType: ''
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    // retrieve data
    const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('vendors');
    itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let items = snapshot.val();
        let newState = [];
        for (let item in items) {
            newState.push({
                id: item,
                name: items[item].username,
                email: items[item].email,
                vendor: items[item].vendorName,
                vendtype: items[item].vendorType
            });
        }
        this.setState({
            items: newState
        });
    });
}
```

And the problem `map`:

```
<ul>
{this.state.items.map((vendors) => {
    return (
        <li key={vendors.id}>
        <h2>{vendors.name}</h2>
        <p>Vendor Name: {vendors.vendorName}
            {vendors.name === this.state.user.username || vendors.user === this.state.user.email ?
                <button onClick={() => this.remoteItem(vendors.id)}>Remove Item</button> : null}
            </p>
        </li>
    )
})}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an empty state `items` array in the constructor to avoid the `undefined`error in `render()`:

```
this.state = { items: [] }
```

This is just an idea, as ignore how your constructor looks like.

Comment: This renders the page in full! Now to get the database to print the values ex. `{vendors.vendorName}`

Comment: You want to show `vendors.vendorName`, but when you map the retrieved entries to the state there's no `vendorName` field, it's `vendor` instead: `vendor: items[item].vendorName` .I suggest you stick to the field names you have used when setting the state, or you change them to match the ones used in your database (which would make more sense but may not always be possible).

Comment: This makes sense, but there is now an error stating an undefined error when pushing info from the form: https://codepen.io/hugerobots/pen/YeMWbY?editors=1010

Answer (score 1):

With React, at the time this component mounts and loads the jsx. this.state.items doesn't exist yet or is empty. You can use a conditional.

```
{this.state.items.length > 0 ?
{this.state.items.map((vendors) => {
    return (
        <li key={vendors.id}>
        <h2>{vendors.name}</h2>
        <p>Vendor Name: {vendors.vendorName}
            {vendors.name === this.state.user.username || vendors.user === this.state.user.email ?
                <button onClick={() => this.remoteItem(vendors.id)}>Remove Item</button> : null}
            </p>
        </li>
    )
})} 
: <h1>Asynccccc</h1> }
```

I think you may have some async issues. try this.

```
componentDidMount() {
// retrieve data
let items;
let newState = [];
const itemsRef = firebase.database().ref("vendors");
itemsRef
  .on("value", snapshot => {
    items = snapshot.val();
    for (let item in items) {
      newState.push({
        id: item,
        name: items[item].username,
        email: items[item].email,
        vendor: items[item].vendorName,
        vendtype: items[item].vendorType
      });
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.setState(
      {
        items: newState
      },
      function() {
        console.log(
          "Maybe you were setting state before your for each finishes"
        );
      }
    );
  });
```

}

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I'm thrown this error: `Module build failed: SyntaxError: this is a reserved word 

  
  {this.state.items.length > 0 ?
> {this.state.items.map((vendors) => {`

For claritity, the second `this` is what the console error is pointing to

Comment: Post your entire component. Are you declaring state as constructor(props){super(props) this.state = {}}? Or const state= {}?

Comment: check the updates above. I think setSTate is getting called on newState when it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Try && (and) operator

```
 {this.state.items.length > 0 && this.renderItems()}
```

where

```
renderItems= () => {
   return this.state.items.map((vendors) => {
    return (
        <li key={vendors.id}>
        <h2>{vendors.name}</h2>
        <p>Vendor Name: {vendors.vendorName}
            {vendors.name === this.state.user.username || vendors.user === this.state.user.email ?
                <button onClick={() => this.remoteItem(vendors.id)}>Remove Item</button> : null}
            </p>
        </li>
    )
})
}
```